# Доступ к данным вне контекста в цикле шаблонизатора Golang

Tags: golang, шаблонизаторы

В шаблон передается массив rows и переменная Date. Во время перебора массива в шаблоне контекст меняется и обратиться к .Date из цикла не удаётся. Возможно ли обратится к Date из цикла не встраивая её в каждый элемент массива?

```
{{range $index, $row := .rows}}
  <th>
  {{$row.Name}}
  {{$row.Id}}
  {{.Date}}
  </th>
{{end}}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16734503

Comment: Введите перед циклом локальную переменную `{{$date=.Date}}` и используйте её внутри цикла как `{{$date}}`

Comment: @entrance спасибо за ответ. Подскажите почему многие ответы тут даны как комментарии, а не как полноценный ответ?

Comment: @ПавелАравин, не знаю как остальные, мне просто было лень оформлять ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за комментарии. В них есть ответ на вопрос.
К переданной в шаблон переменной можно обратиться через знак $ например как $.Date так же и к любым другим переменным переданным в шаблон.

Вот такой код будет работать:

```
{{range $index, $row := .rows}}
  <th>
  {{$row.Name}}
  {{$row.Id}}
  {{$.Date}}
  </th>
{{end}}
```